# UIImagePickerController has a black bar at the bottom by default?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an simple UIImagePickerController where I hide the camera controls and set the sourceType to the camera.  This opens the live camera preview right away but there's about a 50px hight black bar at the bottom of the viewer.  Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: it is simply **WHERE THE CAMERA IMAGE ENDS**.  the camera is 4:3 but modern iPhones are much "longer" than that.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Usman for the link.  The ratio seems to be a bit different from what's suggested in the blog.  The ratio of 1.23 works for iPhone 4 and 4s.  Also, in order to preserve the aspect ratio, I suggest scaling both x and y.

```
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    CGAffineTransform cameraTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.23, 1.23);
    picker.cameraViewTransform = cameraTransform;
```

Comment: I have black color on iPhone 5, what ratio i need to given.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the differing aspect ratio of the camera vs. the iPhone screen.